# Saving intermediate variable values of a recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion, save

I'm trying to code a function calculating difference quotients. I need to this for polynomial interpolation. Given nodes `x = linspace(a,b,n+1)`, function values at the nodes `y = func(x)` I want to find the values of difference quotients `f[x0], f[x_0,x_1], ..., f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]`. To calculate `f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]` I will need `f[x_0,x_1,...,x_(n-1)]`, etc., thus it would be a good idea save the intermediate steps on my way to `f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]`, so that on my way to `f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]` I will save the preceding difference quotients as elements of a vector.

Could someone tell me how to correct my code in order to save appropriate difference quotient values? Here's the code:

```
function [fx, all_fx] = ilo2(a,b,x,y,fx,all_fx)
    if a == b
        fx(end+1) = y(a);
        if a == 1
            all_fx(end+1) = fx(end);
        end
        return
    end
    a;
    b;
    [c, all_fx] = ilo2(a+1,b,x,y,fx,all_fx);
    [d, all_fx] = ilo2(a,b-1,x,y,fx,all_fx);
    fx(end+1) = (c-d)/(b-a);
    if a == 1
        all_fx(end+1) = fx(end);
    end
end
```

The difference quotients I need are under '`if a == 1`' condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed it:

```
function [all_fx,fx] = ilo(a,b,x,y,all_fx,fx)
    if a == b
        fx(end+1) = y(a);
        if a == 1
            all_fx(end+1) = fx(end);
        end
        return
    end
    [all_fx,c] = ilo(a+1,b,x,y,all_fx,fx);
    [all_fx,d] = ilo(a,b-1,x,y,all_fx,fx);
    fx(end+1) = (c-d)/(b-a);
    if a == 1
        all_fx(end+1) = fx(end);
    end
end
```